# Adding new layer to existing User Stored Display in ArcFM?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, layers, arcfm

I am trying to help a coworker to add a brand new created layer in our GIS to the User Stored Display that is saved. The saved display existed previous to the new layer being added to the our GIS.

Is this as simple as 'adding data' while having the user stored display active and saving it again?

It would make sense to me that it is that simple but I can't play around with it since I started working later than the other person (who is old school) so I don't have the issue.

I have tried looking around and I can't find anything on it and I do was not able to just try adding the data because my coworker was working on something and they don't believe it is that simple. We are still using ArcMap 10.2. with ArcFM.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Are you using ArcFM?

Comment: Yes we are using ArcFM. So we have it in a user stored display under Stored Displays.

Comment: OK, sorry I don't have ArcFM to test with

Comment: see http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/DesktopUsing/StoredDisplays.html

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242802/adding-new-layer-to-existing-user-stored-display-in-arcfm/260033#comment379735_242802), there is documentation on ArcFM's Stored Displays that should be consulted:

> see http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/DesktopUsing/StoredDisplays.html